# How to apply style for child selector using scss

Tags: css, sass

How to apply style for nth nested child using scss in easier way without deep nesting

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like :

```
.class {
    &:nth-child(odd) {
        // Style here...
    }
}
```

#### Update

As per you comment, you need your CSS written as

```
.contaier.desc {
    .hello2 { 
        .hello3 { 
            background-color-red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: <div class="container desc">
    <div class="hello2">
      <div class="hello2">
        <div class="hello3">
        Hello World
    </div></div>
    </div>
</div> I need to apply style to hello3 using scss

Comment: SO whats are you trying to target??

Comment: can i apply like .contaier desc {.hello3 { background-color-red;}} is this the correct format

Comment: If you want that to work it would be .contaier.desc {.hello { background-color-red;}}. You would need it to read .contaier.desc as you are targeting a element that has two classes of the name container and desc

Comment: i need to apply to 3 level i.e div of class="hello3"

Comment: I've updated the answer so you'd be able to target hello3

Comment: @GauthamShetty and why not simply `.hello3 {}` ??

Comment: @TemaniAfif he's asked how to do this in SASS and presumably, if this is the case, he has other styles to go into the previous attributes. If not, then obviously you're correct

Comment: SASS is also CSS :) and i don't see any needs to complicate all this with this simply html structure unless he's not clear with what he needs

Comment: Actually i want to apply deep nested classname hello-n.But i knw parent is class .container desc.Dont we have easier way instead of nesting to reach the classname.i know in less we can do it.But not sure about scss